# C++ check OS from text file

Tags: c++, linux, windows, macos, dos

How to check which of the operating system was used creating text file? I have 4 text files and they are from Mac, Win, Linux and Dos. How to check which file are from win, mac, linux and dos OS if they are mixed? I know how to check with macros like ifdefine and ech but how to detect from txt file? Thanks

Comment: That´s not possible.

Answer (score 2):

One approach would be to look at the line endings for the files. You can differentiate between Windows/DOS, Unix/Linux (including Mac OS X) and Mac OS 9 and lower line endings.

- Windows/DOS: CRLF characters for line ending
- Unix/Linux (OS X): LF character for line ending
- Mac OS 9 and lower: CR character for line ending

This gives no guarantee that the files were actually created on those platforms though, since it is possible to create files with any of those line endings on any modern OS using various editors, however it may be enough for your purposes.

For more information, see the Wiki article on line endings: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline

Answer (score 1):

There is not a one-to-one mapping of line-ending conventions to platforms. For example, GNU/Linux and Mac OS X both use LF as the newline character. But as a rule of thumb:

- if LF is preceded by CR, the file uses the DOS line-ending convention (Windows)
- if lines are separated by a sole LF, the Unix line-ending convention is used (Linux/Mac OS X)
- Mac OS up to version 9 used a sole CR

You can find an extensive list of platforms and their line-ending conventions here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline